# Combining fine and course multispeed synchro angles

Tags: binary, weighted

I'm looking to combine the binary outputs from a course and a fine synchro, sometimes referred to as combining multispeed resolvers.

The course synchro is connected x1 so its MSB corresponds to a weighting of 180deg and its LSB (10bit) 0.35 deg. The fine synchro is connected via a X36 gearbox so revolves 10 times per revolution of the course synchro so its MSB is weighted at 5 deg. and its LSB (14bit) 0.0006 deg and therefore its weighting does not match the course synchro weighting so cannot simply be added.

The only reference I can find online is for a hardware logic generated application but its translation makes it difficult to see the formula used to match the x36 to the x1 in order to do it in software.
http://www.ecrimpower.com/uploads/file/20180511/14/_1526021615.pdf

So for binary inputs :-
course 1011101110  MSB=180   Each bit is weighted /2 so 180,90,45,22.5 .....
fine   0101110111000 MSB=5   Each bit is weighted /2 so 5,2.5,1.25 .....

The combined output should be 263.671 deg (taken from an existing 1980's display system)

Many thanks
Paul

Comment: It will be cool if you can translate this technical problem to a simple example. If you are trying to combine two streams of data: coarse and fine, then modelling them as Observables and combining observables can be a solution. But I am not even sure I understand your requirement. Do you mean `Angular` in any other context? Can you explain how this is related to Angular Javascript Platform Library?

Comment: Apologises the tag for angular refers to angles  rather than a specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has come up with a solution which I will post here as in case anyone is searching in the future for this sort of thing as there is nothing out there....

First convert the data bits from each synchro by adding the angle of each bit weighting
Course Synchro = BB 80 Hex would be 180 + 45 + 22.5 + 11.25 etc = 263.671 degrees
Fine Synchro = 5D C0 Hex would be 90 + 22.5 + 11.25 + 5.625 etc = 131.835 degrees

Now to combine these two angular positions to give a 12 bit resolution angle we take the course x1 and divide by 10 then take the integer and multiply by 10 to give us the course value on the same weighting as the fine.
263.671/10=26.3671 the Int 26*10=260
we then take the fine synchro x36 and divide by 36 so it has the same weighting as the course x1.
131.835/36=3.6621
Then we simply add the two.
260 + 3.6621 = 263.6621 degrees